# DynamoDB update duplicates records in List field

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm performing an update (or create if it doesn't exist) on a DynamoDB table with the following params:

```json
{
    "TableName": "TableName",
    "Key": {
        "PartitionKey": "TEST#",
        "SortKey": "SK#123456"
    },
    "UpdateExpression": "set WaterTests = list_append(if_not_exists(WaterTests, :empty_list), :waterTestValues),  MakeModel = :mm, Version = :v, Username = :username",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":waterTestValues": [
            {
                "DateTest": "2022-03-29T09:40:50.985Z",
                "IsValid": true,
                "S3Path": "sample/s3/path"
            }
        ],
        ":v": "v1",
        ":mm": "No Make Model",
        ":username": "no.user@redacted.com",
        ":empty_list": []
    },
    "ReturnValues": "UPDATED_NEW"
}
```

It invariably results in the following (for a non existing record, unique HK+SK):

```json
{
    "PartitionKey": "SESSION#",
    "SortKey": "USER#no.user@redacted.com#999fe1b3-0b59-4a41-9eef-37d433566af0",
    "WifiTests": [
    {
    "DateTest": "2022-03-29T09:40:50.985Z",
    "IsValid": true,
    "S3Path": "sample/s3/path"
    },
    {
    "DateTest": "2022-03-29T09:40:50.985Z",
    "IsValid": true,
    "S3Path": "sample/s3/path"
    }
    ]...
```

I'm using a standard update call as follows:

```js
await docClient.update(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(data);
    }).promise();
```

I have no clue on why the duplication always happens.

Comment: Items in a list don't have to be unique. Are you wondering why the item is appended at all? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: The expected behaviour would be to have 1 item in the list after the call is done

Comment: Also @Maurice I kinda get the direction of where your question is going if you're hinting towards the eventual consistency not guaranteeing that duplication doesn't happen (hadn't tought about it), but still surprised it duplicates every single time like clockwork..

Comment: Are you sure, you're doing the call only once and there is no Lambda/whatever retry going on? What you're seeing is the result of the API call being executed twice.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Because the log message of the onsuccess call of the put function already logs the duplicated item, and right before that I log the payload, and it's there only once..